# Javascript read specific line in txt file and assign an id to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a text file structured like so...

> ```
> Hello
> .
> world
> .
> .
> .
> .
> its me
> ```

I using the following code to read the txt file

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readfileautomatically();
</script>
</head>

<body>
<body onload="readfileautomatically();">

<td id="foo"></td>



<script>
function readfileautomatically () {

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/foo.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
alert(client.responseText);
       }
client.send();

}

</script>
</body>
```

Currently with the above I'm able to read the text file and alert the contents. I want to now expand my code and do this.

read foo.txt when page loads

assign line 3 world from the txt file id=line3

assign line 1 hello from the txt file id=line1

So that I can do this:

```
<td="line3"> world from txt file will be here  </td>
<td="line1"> hello from txt file will be here  </td>
```

Any help given would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me know if you had any questions :)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="readfileautomatically();">

<div id="line1"></div>
<div id="line3"></div>

<script>
    function readfileautomatically () {
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open('GET', '/foo.txt');
        client.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if( client.responseText != '' )
            {
                var txt = client.responseText.split("\n");
                document.getElementById("line1").innerHTML = txt[0];
                document.getElementById("line3").innerHTML = txt[2];
            }
        }
        client.send();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you `encodeURI` and `decodeURI` when you could just split with RegEx or `\n` instead?

Answer (score 1):

To split the file into lines, you can try the `String#split` method, splitting by `\n` characters (newlines). This would give you an array of lines.

For instance:

```
var text = client.responseText;
var lines = text.split("\n"); // create array of lines
document.getelementById("line3").innerHTML = lines[2]; // Arrays start at zero
document.getelementById("line1").innerHTML = lines[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/reergymerej/3755btfp/)

You'll have to split the text on the new line character and iterate through the array.  Watch out for [variations between newline on different systems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n)

```
var text = 'Hello\n.\nworld\n.\n.\n.\n.\nits me';

var lines = text.split('\n');
lines.forEach(function (line, i) {
    if (line) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');    
        div.id = 'line' + (i + 1);
        div.innerHTML = line;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

    console.log('%d: %s', i, line);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[Code Source](https://atlxmt.com/guides_htmlcssjs_snippets_js_readllineoftextfileandconverttovariable)

Use this js:

```js
function /*<trigger load function>*/ () {
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '//<path to file>');
client.onreadystatechange = function()
{
var txt = client.responseText.split("\n");
document.getElementById("/*<output variable, include beginning slash>*/").innerHTML = txt[<line, 0-9 style>];
/*<duplicate this line for all lines of the file you would like to read, but dont forget unique numbers>*/
}
client.send();
}
```

Create a <? id="<output variable>"> tag where you want to display the line.

replace "?" with a tag name such as "p", "txt", "div", "xmpl", "rgx" or "<custom>".

"xmpl" and "rgx" are not real tags, they are just preferences, but they have styling in some MT CSS files.

Replace anything enclosed in triangle brackets with the shown type of data. this is not HTML, it's JS.

I have refined the code into pure js code with highlighted modification points.

BTW, you can use "&lt;" and "&gt;" to re-create triangle brackets, and "&amp;" for the ampersand at the beginning. This code is an ampersand, followed by text(case sensitive) to re-create special characters. a full list is available [here][3].

*some links lead to pages that are coming soon.
*some links lead to a network site made by the maker of this post(do you know?).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `.split()` with argument `RegExp` `/\b/` , utilize `for` loop to iterate resulting array , create `td` element if index of array is `0` : `"Hello"` , `2` : `"world"`

```
<script>
    function readfileautomatically() {
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open("GET", "/foo.txt");
        client.onload = function() {
            var tr = document.querySelector("table tr");
            var res = this.responseText.split(/\b/);
            var text = " from txt file will be here";
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                if (i === 0) {
                    var elem = document.createElement("td");
                    elem.id = "line" + 1;
                    elem.innerHTML = res[i] + text;
                    tr.appendChild(elem);
                } else if (i === 2) {
                    var elem = document.createElement("td");
                    elem.innerHTML = res[i].toLowerCase() + text;
                    elem.id = "line" + i;
                    tr.insertBefore(elem, tr.lastChild)
                }
            }
        }
        client.send();   
    }
</script>
<body onload="readfileautomatically();">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="foo">foo</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pvd0q36x/